# Sort an array based on data in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays of objects like below:

```
items = [{"id":"5","tobuy":"1","name":"pop"},
         {"id":"6","tobuy":"1","name":"fish"},
         {"id":"7","tobuy":"0","name":"soda"}]
pkgs =  [{"item_id":"5","store":"Market","aisle":"3"},
         {"item_id":"6","store":"Market","aisle":"2"},
         {"item_id":"6","store":"Dept","aisle":"8"},
         {"item_id":"7","store":"Market","aisle":"4"}]
```

I'm trying to sort the items array, but I want to leverage the data in the pkgs array.
The "item_id" field in the pkgs array corresponds to the "id" field in the items array.
For example, I want to sort:

> - first by "tobuy" in descending order
> - then by "store"
> - then by "aisle"
> - then by "name"

While item_id and id correspond between the two arrays, there is not a 1 to 1 relationship.  There could be 0 or more pkgs that correspond to any given item.

(If I had a database, I would just join the tables, but in JavaScript I just have the two related arrays).

I'm not sure how to build the comparator function and pass in the second array.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can use underscoreJS.

Comment: @Vural,  I looked through the [underscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) functions and I'm not sure how it helps.  Can you provide any additional direction?  Thanks

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript , find the dynamicSort

Comment: @VuralAcar, I've reviewed dynamicSort on this link, but it only sorts relative to the multiple fields in the single array.  I need to use the data from the second array to sort the first array.

Comment: So are you looking to join the two array together with matching `id` and `item_id`?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy,  I don't really want to join the two together in the end.  I only need the data from pkgs during the sort.  In the end I only want the data in the original items array (just sorted).  Do I have to join the two arrays and then strip out the data from the pkgs array after doing the sort?

Comment: lookup Schwartzian Transform in Perl - basically, it is a map to augment the one array with the to-be-sorted field from the other array, followed by a sort, followed by a map to strip the augmented value from the sorted result.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Exactly what the first part of my answer does ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
items = items.map(function (item, index) {
    return {
        item: item,
        pkg: pkgs[index] //I assumed associated pkgs were at the same index
    };
}).sort(function (a, b) {
   var pkgA = a.pkg, pkgB = b.pkg, r;

   r = +b.item.tobuy - +a.item.tobuy;

   if (r !== 0) return r;

   r = pkgA.store < pkgB.store? -1 : (pkgA.store === pkgB.store? 0 : 1);

   if (r !== 0) return r;

   r = +pkgA.aisle - +pkgB.aisle;

   if (r !== 0) return r;

   return pkgA.name < pkgB.name? -1 : (pkgA.name === pkgB.name? 0 : 1);

}).map(function (item) {
    return item.item;
});
```

Instead of merging the data, you could also create a lookup map that allows to quickly retrieve the associated package directly from the sort function.

E.g.

```
var pkgsMap = pkgs.reduce(function (res, pkg) {
    res[pkg.item_id] = pkg;
    return res;
}, {});
```

Then in the sort function you can do:

```
var pkgA = pkgsMap[a.id], pkgB = pkgsMap[b.id];
```

**EDIT:**

> There is actually another field in the pkgs array called "ppu" which
>   is the price per unit. The lowest ppu is the one that would be used.

You can just build your package map using the following and then use the map in the sort function to retrieve the associated package like described above and implement the sort algorithm.

```
var pkgsMap = pkgs.sort(function (a, b) {
    //not sure what ppu is so I sort it as a string
    return a.ppu < b.ppu? -1 : Number(a.ppu > b.ppu);
}).reduce(function (res, pkg) {
    if (!(pkg.item_id in res)) res[pkg.item_id] = pkg;
    return res;
}, {});
```

Comment: +1 for the Schwartzian Transform (though it is a bit longer than the ST's I'm used to seeing ;-)

Comment: @plalx, I should have mentioned earlier, the indexes between the two arrays are not the same.  There may be 0 or more pkgs that correspond to a single item.

Comment: @Simpler How do you want to deal with cases where multiple packages are associated with a single item?

Comment: @Simpler As for the index not being the same, you can simply use the second approach that I describe to get the associated package.

Comment: @plalx, There is actually another field in the pkgs array called "ppu" which is the price per unit.  The lowest ppu is the one that would be used.  (In trying to simplify the problem in the original post, I left out some useful information by mistake.)

Comment: @Simpler, I updated my answer. You should have everything you need to solve you problem now. If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that generates a comparator, this looks unwieldy but means you can generate any sort order desired

```
function generateComparator(dict, index, order) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var i, key, direction,
            ai = a[index], av,
            bi = b[index], bv;
        for (i = 0; i < order.length; ++i) {
            key = order[i].key;
            direction = +!!order[i].reverse || -1;
            if (dict[ai].hasOwnProperty(key)) // if in dict, lookup
                av = dict[ai][key];
            else                              // else look up in item
                av = a[key];
            if (dict[bi].hasOwnProperty(key))
                bv = dict[ai][key];
            else
                bv = b[key];
            // console.log(i, key, av, bv, direction); // debug
            if (av === bv)
                continue;
            if (av < bv)
                return direction;
            return -direction;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
```

Convert your *Arrays* into a dictionary

```
var dict = (function (arr, index) {
    var o = {}, i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        o[arr[i][index]] = arr[i];
    }
    return o;
}(pkgs, 'item_id'));
```

Define your sort choices

```
var order = [
    {key: 'tobuy', reverse: 1},
    {key: 'store'},
    {key: 'aisle'},
    {key: 'name'}
];
```

Generate comparator with dictionary

```
var comparator = generateComparator(dict, 'id', order);
```

Then sort your first *Array*

```
items.sort(comparator);
/* [
    {"id": "6", "tobuy": "1", "name": "fish"},
    {"id": "5", "tobuy": "1", "name": "pop"},
    {"id": "7", "tobuy": "0", "name": "soda"}
] */
```

Comment: +1, I believe that it would be more reusable to let the client code merge the properties and have a `generateComparator` function that doesn't rely on an external source of data. Also, you may want to account for `'9' > '11'` which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @plalx OP uses _String_ for them so I didn't want to make guesses. The external `dict` for `generateComparator` was to make it as generic as possible, of course if it's not suitable, changes could always be made, but I hope I got the "difficult" concepts down so such modification requires minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider how you would do this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN pkgs ON items.id = pkgs.item_id
ORDER BY tobuy DESC, store, aisle, name
```

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17500836/783743) demonstrates how to implement an inner join and an equijoin in JavaScript:

```
function equijoin(primary, foreign, primaryKey, foreignKey, select) {
    var m = primary.length, n = foreign.length, index = [], c = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {     // loop through m items
        var row = primary[i];
        index[row[primaryKey]] = row; // create an index for primary table
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {     // loop through n items
        var y = foreign[j];
        var x = index[y[foreignKey]]; // get corresponding row from primary
        c.push(select(x, y));         // select only the columns you need
    }

    return c;
}
```

Now you can use `equijoin` to join `items` and `pkgs` as follows:

```
equijoin(items, pkgs, "id", "item_id", function (item, pkg) {
    return {
        id: +item.id,
        tobuy: +item.tobuy,
        store: pkg.store,
        aisle: +pkg.aisle,
        name: item.name
    };
});
```

Note that I'm coercing `item.id`, `item.tobuy` and `pkg.aisle` to numbers by applying the unary `+` operator to them.

Now that we joined the two tables we need to sort them. To sort the table we use the built-in array [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    // ORDER BY tobuy DESC

    var aTobuy = a.tobuy, bTobuy = b.tobuy;

    if (aTobuy < bTobuy) return 1;
    if (aTobuy > bTobuy) return -1;

    // ORDER BY store

    var aStore = a.store, bStore = b.store;

    if (aStore < bStore) return -1;
    if (aStore > bStore) return 1;

    // ORDER BY aisle

    var aAisle = a.aisle, bAisle = b.aisle;

    if (aAisle < bAisle) return -1;
    if (aAisle > bAisle) return 1;

    // ORDER BY name

    var aName = a.name, bName = b.name;

    if (aName < bName) return -1;
    if (aName > bName) return 1;

    // keep them unchanged

    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

The `sort` method is [unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (i.e. it might not preserve the ordering of items with equal sort value in the input list). Hence to workaround this limitation we return `a.id - b.id` as the last statement.

Also notice that we're comparing all the values (whether strings or numbers) using `<` and `>`. Strings are compared lexicographically while numbers are compared numerically.

Put together the code is as follows:

```
var table = equijoin(items, pkgs, "id", "item_id", function (item, pkg) {
    return {
        id: +item.id,
        tobuy: +item.tobuy,
        store: pkg.store,
        aisle: +pkg.aisle,
        name: item.name
    };
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var aTobuy = a.tobuy, bTobuy = b.tobuy;

    if (aTobuy < bTobuy) return 1;
    if (aTobuy > bTobuy) return -1;

    var aStore = a.store, bStore = b.store;

    if (aStore < bStore) return -1;
    if (aStore > bStore) return 1;

    var aAisle = a.aisle, bAisle = b.aisle;

    if (aAisle < bAisle) return -1;
    if (aAisle > bAisle) return 1;

    var aName = a.name, bName = b.name;

    if (aName < bName) return -1;
    if (aName > bName) return 1;

    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

Not as concise as SQL is it? Anyway, see the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZG96/

---

**Edit:** If you want only want the `id`, `tobuy` and `name` columns then you can extract it from the sorted table using `map` as follows:

```
table.map(function (item) {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        tobuy: item.tobuy,
        name: item.name
    };
});
```

This corresponds to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id, tobuy, name FROM (SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN pkgs
ON items.id = pkgs.item_id ORDER BY tobuy DESC, store, aisle, name)
```

See the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZG96/1/

Comment: +1, it would be sad not to be rewarded for taking the time to write such a quality answer ;)