# Retrieve two lists, sort and compare values, then display all the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting, sharepoint

I have two lists in SharePoint 2013 Online. I need to get matching values for a user-entered key (string), sort, and display both lists as one. Easy enough if I were able to use SQL to create a view. Best solution seems to be to just display both lists.

I've tried using SPD Linked Sources, but the "linked field" option never displays and the no-preview SPD is awful (what were MS thinking?). Workflow isn't feasible. List items may be edited in 'datasheet view' (client requirement). Lookups require a selection to display the related field.

I can get both lists and display them separately.

What I have:

```
List 1                          List 2
fruit apple  type rome          fruit apple  state washington
fruit pear   type bartlett      fruit pear   state oregon
fruit grapes type red           fruit orange state florida
```

What I want:

```
fruit apple  type rome      state washington 
fruit grapes type red 
fruit orange                state florida
fruit pear   type bartlett  state oregon
```

I'm missing two things (maybe more) an array that I can use for sorting and a comparison to use for matching the fruit on both lists. The real lists may have 50-120 items (each) that need to be matched.

All items should be returned. If there's a match, the data should be in the same row. If not, blanks should display.

The code below displays via an html page where the ID for each of the table cells matches the cell references in the script below. It's not sorted and the rows don't match.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "sharepointlist/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items",

    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }, 
    }).success(function (data) {

        var title = '';
        var type = '';
         $.each(data.d.results, 
        function (key, value) {

        title += "Title: " + value.Title + "<br/>";
        type += "Type: " + value.Type  + "<br/>";
        }); 

    $("#tdtitle").html(title);
    $("#tdtype").html(status);

$.ajax({
    url: "sharepointlist/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List2')/items",

    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }, 
    }).success(function (data) {

        var title2 = '';
        var state = '';
         $.each(data.d.results, 
        function (key, value) {

        title2 += "Title2: " + value.Title + "<br/>";
        city += "State: " + value.State + "<br/>";
        }); 

    $("#tdsecond").html(title2);
    $("#tdstate").html(city);
```

Comment: This obviously requires some data mapping. What is the specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to perform the "join" operation on list items returned from REST queries. If so, you could consider the following approach

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,selectProperties){
   return $.getJSON( webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=" + selectProperties.join(','))
   .then(function(data){
        return data.value.map(function(item){
             return selectProperties.reduce(function(result, key) { 
                 result[key] = item[key]; 
                 return result; 
             },{});    
        });
    });    
}


function joinListItems(left, right, key) {
    if(left.length == 0 || right.length == 0)
        return new Error("No data was found");


    var columns = Object.keys(left[0]).concat(Object.keys(right[0]));

    var createRow = function(left,right){
        var row = {};
        columns.forEach(function(key){
          row[key] = null;
        });
        var values = left != null ? left : right;
        for(var name in values) row[name] = values[name];
        return row;
    };
    var updateRow = function(existingRow,values){
        for(var name in values) existingRow[name] = values[name];
    };

    return left.concat(right).reduce(function(result, current, index){ 

      if(index < left.length){ 
           result.rows.push(createRow(current,null));   
           result.keys[current[key]] = index;
      }
      else {
           var rowIdx = result.keys[current[key]];
           if(typeof rowIdx !== 'undefined'){
               updateRow(result.rows[rowIdx],current);
           }
           else {
               result.rows.push(createRow(null,current));
           }
      } 

      return result;
    },{rows: [], keys: {}}).rows;

}



$.when(
    // Get List1
    getListItems( _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, "List1",['Title','Type']),
    // Get List2
    getListItems( _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, "List2",['Title','State'])

)
.then(function(items1,items2){
    var key='Title';
    var result = joinListItems(items1,items2,key);

    result = result.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
    //displayResults(result);
});


//print results (from comment section) 
function displayResults(items){
   var title = ''; 
   var type = ''; 
   $.each(items, function (index, item) { 
       title += "Title: " + item.Title + "<br/>"; 
       type += "Type: " + item.Type + "<br/>"; 
   });
}
```

> You also  might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500312/is-there-some-way-i-can-join-the-contents-of-two-javascript-arrays-much-like-i) helpful that specifically discusses
>   join operation.

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "Title": "fruit apple",
    "Type": "type rome",
    "State": "state washington"
  },
  {
    "Title": "fruit grapes",
    "Type": "type red",
    "State": null
  },
  {
    "Title": "fruit orange",
    "State": "state florida",
    "Type": null
  },
  {
    "Title": "fruit pear",
    "Type": "type bartlett",
    "State": "state oregon"
  }
]
```

**Update for sort function**

Replace:

```
 result = result.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title);
});
```

with

```
result = result.sort(function(a, b){
    if(!a.Title) a.Title = "";
    if(!b.Title) b.Title = "";
    return a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title);
});
```

Comment: Yes. That is my goal. I need to study your solution. The result you show is precisely what I want.

Comment: Vadim, This seems to be a clean solution that could be expanded easily. The separation is nice. Took me awhile before it made sense to me. Everything seems to be working up to the very end. 'items1,items2' seem to need a definition? The code runs, the lists are retrieved -- but there's no data (looking at the console). I'm getting an error 'Unable to get property 'localeCompare' of undefined or null reference' which tells me ?there's no data. Not sure how to correct this. The other examples (MS) use a different method with variables.

Comment: Terri, I've verified it once again in Chrome (v48) and IE (v 11) and the provided example works for me.. It seems you are getting list data where Title field could contain null values, could you please try the updated version of sort function (see **update** section in the answer)

Comment: Vadim, that was it. I had two items where the Title was null. THANK YOU!

Comment: 'JSON.stringify' works and I can see the result is correct. But I don't know how to separate it. Tried 'JSON.parse(result)' but that is not correct. I managed to include a '<br />' tag but still have the brackets and braces. Looked at the replace (above = null) options and that confused me even more. Have been looking and testing for 4 hours now and can't find any samples to help. The original method 'value.Title' etc. was verbose (and not what I needed) but I understood what it was doing and could manipulate it. How to manipulate the JSON output so I can put it into a human-friendly format?

Comment: I was missing the final step

The JSON returned correctly, -- $.each() The following works (where "result" is the variable that holds the data)

var title = '';
var type = '';
$.each(result, function (index, value) {
    title += "Title: " + value.Title + "<br/>";
    type += "Type: " + value.Type  + "<br/>";
});

Comment: Terri, glad to hear that, somehow i missed your previous comment

Comment: Vadim, would you edit your solution to include this last piece for the output? That way there's a nicely formatted block that others could see instead of the mushed version in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would divide task in two parts.

First of all you need to combine data retrieved from `GET` calls.

You may consider using promises for that in a way:

```
$.when(
    // Get List1
    $.get("sharepointlist/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/item").then( function(data) {
        return data.d.results;
    }),

    // Get List2
    $.get("sharepointlist/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List2')/items").then( function(data) {
        return data.d.results;
    })

).then(processData);

function processData(list1, list2) {
    var res = list1.concat(list2);
}
```

Now you need to process your data. First of all you sort your new array by `Title`.

```
newData = newData.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title);
});
```

Now you need to loop through sorted data and combine objects with the same Title.

```
res = res.reduce(function(a, b) {
    var t = a.slice(-1)[0]; //it's like getting last element
    if (t && t.Title === b.Title) {
        if (b.State) {
            t.State = b.State;
        } else {
            t.Type = b.Type;
        }
    } else {
        a.push(b);
    }
    return a;
}, []);
```

Now just assign new data into DOM.

**UPDATE:**

The example of merging all properties while joining elements using jQuery `$.extend()`.

```
res = res.reduce(function(a, b) {
            var t = a.slice(-1)[0]; //it's like getting last element
            if (t && t.Title === b.Title) {
                $.extend(t, b);
            } else {
                a.push(b);
            }
            return a;
        }, []);
```

PS: jQuery `$.extend()` ignores, properties that are null or undefined.

The link to working solution at Plunkr with hardcoded JSON files.

https://plnkr.co/edit/gYJjyT8lCCNTe6EAlSYB

Comment: I will try it and let you know. THANK YOU!

Comment: @teamnorge, this is a correct approach but I would like to make a few suggestions 1) I would suggest to utilize $.getJSON instead of .$.get to return results in json format 2) may be it would be better to implement join algorithm as more generic as demonstrated in my example

Comment: teamnorge, Thank you for getting me started. $when is the key. I put your code into my setup and tried it, but either I couldn't get the data or (after I replaced the clean, simple $get with the $ajax block), I got object, Object (ok can fix that) and then a syntax error at the ').then(processData); line. Checked and rechecked but couldn't find my mistake. The sample seemed to be not working for me either. Just not my day. Progress though, thanks to both of you.