# How to merge multiple array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have multiple arrays and I want to merge the data of all the array into one array of objects .
All the data will be merged on the basis of the key so how to make one production level code so that it will merge all the data.

```
results[0]= 
    [ {categoryGroupID: '1231',categoryID: '12311',categoryName: 'External'},
    {categoryGroupID: '1231',categoryID: '12312',categoryName: 'Internal'},
    {categoryGroupID: '1231',categoryID: '141414141',categoryName: ''},
    {categoryGroupID: '1232',categoryID: '12321',categoryName: 'Style'},
    {categoryGroupID: '1233',categoryID: '123222',categoryName: ''},
    {categoryGroupID: '1233',categoryID: '12331',categoryName: 'Customer Satisfaction'}]

results[1]=
  [ { categoryGroupID: '1231',categoryGroupName: 'Store ambience'},
    { categoryGroupID: '1232',categoryGroupName: 'Communication'},
    {categoryGroupID: '1233',categoryGroupName: 'Overall Satisfaction'},
    {categoryGroupID: '12331',categoryGroupName: null}]


results[2]=
    [ {categoryID: '12311',questionID: '12311111',questionName: 'tell me snything'},
    {categoryID: '12312',questionID: '12311113',questionName: 'whatever'},
    {categoryID: '12311',questionID: '123ques',questionName: 'ashjsh'},
    {categoryID: '12311',questionID: '123test',questionName: null}]

results[3]=
  [ { questionID: '12311113',choiceID: '1231111111',choiceValue: 'good'},
    { questionID: '12311113',choiceID: '1231111112',choiceValue: 'very good'},
    {questionID: '12311113',choiceID: '12311113113',choiceValue: 'bad'}]
```

MY output should like this so how to do it

```
"categoryGroup": 
[
{"categoryGroupID": "1231","categoryGroupName": "Store ambience",
"category": [
    {"categoryID": "12312","categoryName": "Internal",   

                "question": [
                {"questionID": "12311113","questionName": "whatever",
                      "choice": [
                        {"choiceID": "1231111111","choiceValue": "good"},
                        {"choiceID": "1231111112","choiceValue": "very good"},
                        {"choiceID": "12311113113","choiceValue": "bad",}
                                 ],
            }]
        }, 
    {"categoryID": "12311","categoryName": "External",

            "question": [
                {"questionID": "12311111","questionName": "tell me snything",},
                {"questionID": "123ques","questionName": "ashjsh",}, 
                {"questionID": "123test","questionName": null,}
            ]}, 
    {"categoryID": "141414141","categoryName": "",}]
    }, 

{"categoryGroupID": "1232","categoryGroupName": "Communication",     
"category": [
    {"categoryID": "12321","categoryName": "Style"}]
     }, 

{"categoryGroupID": "1233","categoryGroupName": "Overall Satisfaction",
"category": [
    {"categoryID": "123222","categoryName": "",},
    {"categoryID": "12331","categoryName": "Customer Satisfaction",}]
    },

{"categoryGroupID": "12331","categoryGroupName": null}
]
```

Comment: I don't think there is any out of the box solution for this in vanilla JS

Comment: Then how to solve this by using map or foreach or any other concept can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500312/is-there-some-way-i-can-join-the-contents-of-two-javascript-arrays-much-like-i, maybe it could help

Comment: @ASN, I think, you should give it a try yourself, if you still find it difficult, you can post the code that you have tried and we can work on it from there.

Comment: I have tried in differnt ways but not able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the depths of all this and how you will pretty much need to manually handle all cases here is an example of how it *can* work (probably not should work).

This is based on the indexes (0, 1, 2, 3) of results will always be the same and employs the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `Array` functions. For performance I am not sure how well this will work in a large scenario.

```js
var results = {};

results[0] =
    [{ categoryGroupID: '1231', categoryID: '12311', categoryName: 'External' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1231', categoryID: '12312', categoryName: 'Internal' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1231', categoryID: '141414141', categoryName: '' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1232', categoryID: '12321', categoryName: 'Style' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1233', categoryID: '123222', categoryName: '' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1233', categoryID: '12331', categoryName: 'Customer Satisfaction' }];

results[1] =
  [{ categoryGroupID: '1231', categoryGroupName: 'Store ambience' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1232', categoryGroupName: 'Communication' },
    { categoryGroupID: '1233', categoryGroupName: 'Overall Satisfaction' },
    { categoryGroupID: '12331', categoryGroupName: null }];


results[2] =
    [{ categoryID: '12311', questionID: '12311111', questionName: 'tell me snything' },
    { categoryID: '12312', questionID: '12311113', questionName: 'whatever' },
    { categoryID: '12311', questionID: '123ques', questionName: 'ashjsh' },
    { categoryID: '12311', questionID: '123test', questionName: null }];

results[3] =
  [{ questionID: '12311113', choiceID: '1231111111', choiceValue: 'good' },
    { questionID: '12311113', choiceID: '1231111112', choiceValue: 'very good' },
    { questionID: '12311113', choiceID: '12311113113', choiceValue: 'bad' }];



var o = {
    categoryGroup: results[1].map(function (categoryGroup) {
        var categoryGroup = {
            categoryGroupID: categoryGroup.categoryGroupID,
            categoryGroupName: categoryGroup.categoryGroupName
        };

        categoryGroup['category'] = results[0].filter(function (item) { return item.categoryGroupID == categoryGroup.categoryGroupID })
                                              .map(function (item) {
                                                  return {
                                                      categoryId: item.categoryID,
                                                      categoryName: item.categoryName,
                                                      question: results[2].filter(function (ques) { return ques.categoryID == item.categoryID })
                                                                          .map(function (ques) {
                                                                              return {
                                                                                  questionId: ques.questionID,
                                                                                  questionName: ques.questionName,
                                                                                  choice: results[3].filter(function (ch) { return ch.questionID == ques.questionID })
                                                                                                    .map(function (ch) {
                                                                                                        return {
                                                                                                            choiceID: ch.choiceID,
                                                                                                            choiceValue: ch.choiceValue
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    })
                                                                              }
                                                                          })
                                                  };
                                              });
        return categoryGroup;
    })
};
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score -3):

See this **->** **[How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)**

```
var array1 = ["1","2"];
var array2 = ["3", "4"];

var array3 = array1.concat(array2); // Merges both arrays
// [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
```

for the Apache Commons Lang Array Utils see this  **->** [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

js versions are **dojo** http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/array.html and **util-array** https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-array

This is another dojo example **http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-to-concatenate-arrays-in-Dojo-td3744293.html**

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=ArrayUtil

Comment: but i am using javascript

Comment: OP wants his solution in 'Javascript'