# Efficient mapping of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming

**I am trying to find out the best / most efficient or most functional way to compare / merge / manipulate two arrays (lists) simultaneously in JS.**

The example I give below is a simple example of the overall concept. In my current project, I deal with some very crazy list mapping, filtering, etc. with very large lists of objects.

As delinated below, my first idea (`version1`) on comparing lists would be to run through the first list (i.e. map), and in the anonymous/callback function, filter the second list to meet the criteria needed for the compare (match ids for example). This obviously works, as per `version1` below.

I had a question performance-wise, as by this method on every iteration/call of map, the entire 2nd list gets filtered just to find that one item that matches the filter.

> Also, the filter passes every other item in list2 which should be matched in list1. Meaning (as that sentence probably did not make sense):
>
> ```
> list1.map   list2.filter
>
> id:1        [id:3,id:2,id:1]
>                           ^-match
> id:2        [id:3,id:2,id:1]
>                      ^-match
> id:3        [id:3,id:2,id:1]
>                 ^-match
> ```
>
> Ideally on the first iteration of map (`list1 id:1`), when the filter encounters `list2 id:3` (first item) it would just match it to `list1 id:3`

Thinking with the above concept (matching to a later id when it is encountered earlier, I came up with `version2`).

This makes list2 into a dictionary, and then looks up the value in any sequence by key.

```
const list1 = [
  {id: '1',init:'init1'},
  {id: '2',init:'init2'},
  {id: '3',init:'init3'}
];
const list2 = [
  {id: '2',data:'data2'},
  {id: '3',data:'data3'},
  {id: '4',data:'data4'}
];

/* ---------
* version 1
*/

const mergedV1 = list1.map(n => (
  {...n,...list2.filter(f => f.id===n.id)[0]}
));
/* [ 
  {"id": "1", "init": "init1"}, 
  {"id": "2", "init": "init2", "data": "data2"}, 
  {"id": "3", "init": "init3", "data": "data3"} 
] */

/* ---------
* version 2
*/

const dictList2 = list2.reduce((dict,item) => (dict[item.id]=item,dict),{}); 
// does not handle duplicate ids but I think that's 
// outside the context of this question.

const mergedV2 = list1.map(n => ({...n,...dictList2[n.id]}));
/* [ 
  {"id": "1", "init": "init1"}, 
  {"id": "2", "init": "init2", "data": "data2"}, 
  {"id": "3", "init": "init3", "data": "data3"} 
] */

JSON.stringify(mergedV1) === JSON.stringify(mergedV2);
// true

// and just for fun
const sqlLeftOuterJoinInJS = list1 => list2 => on => {
  const dict = list2.reduce((dict,item) => ( 
    dict[item[on]]=item,dict
  ),{});
  return list1.map(n => ({...n,...dict[n[on]]}
))};
```

Obviously the above examples are pretty simple (merging two lists, each list having a length of 3). There are more complex instances that I am working with.

I don't know if there are some smarter (and ideally functional) techniques out there that I should be using.

Comment: Are any of the arrays supposed to contain a unique set of objects by id?  Meaning is `id` only expected to appear once per value in either of the arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a closure over the wanted key for the group and a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting all objects.

```js
function merge(key) {
    var map = new Map;
    return function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(o => {
            if (!map.has(o[key])) r.push(map.set(o[key], {}).get(o[key]));
            Object.assign(map.get(o[key]), o);
        });
        return r;
    };
}

const
    list1 = [{ id: '1', init: 'init1' }, { id: '2', init: 'init2' }, { id: '3', init: 'init3' }],
    list2 = [{ id: '2', data: 'data2' }, { id: '3', data: 'data3' }, { id: '4', data: 'data4' }],
    result = [list1, list2].reduce(merge('id'), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's beautiful

Comment: looks pretty brilliant. got me looking way more at `map`. one question I have is what does the `Object.assign(map.get(o[key]), o);` do without a left-hand assignment? Is it mutating `o`?

Comment: it mutates the first parameter (the result of `map.get(o[key])`) and assigns the second `o` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` for search is a misstep. Your instinct in version 2 is much better. `Map` and `Set` provide much faster lookup times.

Here's a decomposed approach. It should be pretty fast, but maybe not as fast as Nina's. She is a speed demon >_<

```js
const merge = (...lists) =>
  Array .from
    ( lists
        .reduce (merge1, new Map)
        .values ()
    )

const merge1 = (cache, list) =>
  list .reduce
    ( (cache, l) =>
        cache .has (l.id)
          ? update (cache, l.id, l)
          : insert (cache, l.id, l)
    , cache
    )

const insert = (cache, key, value) =>
  cache .set (key, value)

const update = (cache, key, value) =>
  cache .set
    ( key
    , { ...cache .get (key)
      , ...value
      }
    )

const list1 =
  [{ id: '1', init: 'init1' }, { id: '2', init: 'init2' }, { id: '3', init: 'init3' }]

const list2 =
  [{ id: '2', data: 'data2' }, { id: '3', data: 'data3' }, { id: '4', data: 'data4' }]

console .log (merge (list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering this for completeness as I think Nina and @user633183 have offered most likely more efficient solutions.

If you wish to stick to your initial *filter* example, which is a max lookup N*M, and your arrays are mutable; you could consider reducing the set as you traverse through.  In the old days shrinking the array had a huge impact on performance.

The general pattern today is to use a Map (or dict) as indicated in other answers, as it is both easy to understand and generally efficient.

## Find and Resize

```js
const list1 = [
  {id: '1',init:'init1'},
  {id: '2',init:'init2'},
  {id: '3',init:'init3'}
];
const list2 = [
  {id: '2',data:'data2'},
  {id: '3',data:'data3'},
  {id: '4',data:'data4'}
];

// combine by ID
let merged = list1.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  acc.push(obj);

  // find index by ID
  let foundIdx = list2.findIndex( el => el.id==obj.id );
  // if found, store and remove from search
  if ( foundIdx >= 0 ){
    obj.data = list2[foundIdx].data;
    list2.splice( foundIdx, 1 );        // shrink lookup array
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

// store remaining (if you want); i.e. {id:4,data:'data4'}
merged = merged.concat(list2)

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I should mark this question as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17500312/783743) because you phrased it differently. Anyway, here's my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17500836/783743) to that question copied verbatim. What you want is an `equijoin`:

```js
const equijoin = (xs, ys, primary, foreign, sel) => {
    const ix = xs.reduce((ix, row) => // loop through m items
        ix.set(row[primary], row),    // populate index for primary table
    new Map);                         // create an index for primary table

    return ys.map(row =>              // loop through n items
        sel(ix.get(row[foreign]),     // get corresponding row from primary
        row));                        // select only the columns you need
};
```

You can use it as follows:

```js
const equijoin = (xs, ys, primary, foreign, sel) => {
    const ix = xs.reduce((ix, row) => ix.set(row[primary], row), new Map);
    return ys.map(row => sel(ix.get(row[foreign]), row));
};

const list1 = [
    { id: "1", init: "init1" },
    { id: "2", init: "init2" },
    { id: "3", init: "init3" }
];

const list2 = [
    { id: "2", data: "data2" },
    { id: "3", data: "data3" },
    { id: "4", data: "data4" }
];

const result = equijoin(list2, list1, "id", "id",
    (row2, row1) => ({ ...row1, ...row2 }));

console.log(result);
```

It takes `O(m + n)` time to compute the answer using `equijoin`. However, if you already have an index then it'll only take `O(n)` time. Hence, if you plan to do multiple equijoins using the same tables then it might be worthwhile to abstract out the index.