# JavaScript: SQL-like join of two arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have arrays like this:

```
const one = [
  {id: 1, field1: "a"},
  {id: 2, field1: "b"},
  {id: 3, field1: "c"},
  {id: 4, field1: "d"}
]

const two = [
  {id: 4, field2: "4"},
  {id: 1, field2: "1"}
]
// what I want to achieve:
const result = [
  {id: 1, field1: "a", field2: "1"},
  {id: 4, field1: "d", field2: "4"}
]
```

I want to merge one and two, so I get the result. This is very similar to a SQL join, but I want to do all of this in JavaScript code. Notice:

1. This is "joining" by the `id` "column."
2. The order of the result is the order of the `one` array (sorting by ID is only **coincidentally** the same order)
3. Fields from both arrays exist on the result

I've figured out how to do this on my own, but the code is clunky and difficult to read. Basically, you filter over `one` and remove elements that don't exist in `two`, then you map over `one` and merge the fields of the `two` array.

Is there a more concise way of achieving this? I'm using lodash, and I was hoping there was a function in there to make this easier, but I haven't found any.

Comment: You can accomplish this with .reduce for sure.

Comment: So use JS database: https://www.npmjs.com/package/database-js

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504827/8683285

Comment: why do you have `field1` and `field2`?

Comment: @Justinas interesting library, but it doesn't seem to completely align with what I'm trying to do. If anything, it's overkill.

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ What I think that one is missing is ordering by the elements of the first array.

Answer (score 4):

Create a dictionary or Map of the 2nd array by the key (`id`), and then filter the 1st array, and keep only items that appear in the dictionary. Afterwards, map the remaining items, and add the relevant items from the dictionary.

```js
const joinBy = (arr1, arr2, key) => {
  const arr2Dict = _.keyBy(arr2, key)
  
  return arr1
    .filter(item => item[key] in arr2Dict)
    .map(item => ({ ...item, ...arr2Dict[item[key]] }))
}

const one = [{id: 1, field1: "a"},{id: 2, field1: "b"},{id: 3, field1: "c"},{id: 4, field1: "d"}]
const two = [{id: 4, field2: "4"},{id: 1, field2: "1"}];

const result = joinBy(one, two, 'id')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you don't want to use lodash, you can easily replace `_.keyBy()`, and create an object using `Array.reduce()` or create a Map with `Array.map()`.

```js
const joinBy = (arr1, arr2, key) => {
  const arr2Dict = new Map(arr2.map(o => [o[key], o]))
  
  return arr1
    .filter(item => arr2Dict.has(item[key]))
    .map(item => ({ ...item, ...arr2Dict.get(item[key]) }))
}

const one = [{id: 1, field1: "a"},{id: 2, field1: "b"},{id: 3, field1: "c"},{id: 4, field1: "d"}]
const two = [{id: 4, field2: "4"},{id: 1, field2: "1"}];

const result = joinBy(one, two, 'id')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge`, `map` and `find` functions from `lodash`. For sorting - `sortBy`.

```
_.sortBy(
   _.map(two, (n) => _.merge(n, _.find(one, ['id', n.id]))),
   (o) => _.findIndex(one, ['id', o.id]),
);
```

```js
const one = [{id: 1, field1: "a"},{id: 2, field1: "b"},{id: 3, field1: "c"},{id: 4, field1: "d"}], two = [{id: 4, field2: "4"},{id: 1, field2: "1"}];

const r = _.sortBy(
   _.map(two, (n) => _.merge(n, _.find(one, ['id', n.id]))),
   (o) => _.findIndex(one, ['id', o.id]),
);

console.log(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @DanielKaplan Sure, fixed.

Comment: it looks like you are sorting by ID. Like I said, this is only coincidentally the order that i want. I want the order of the first array

Comment: @DanielKaplan You got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different fields, you could take an object with the reference to the items and map `two` and sort by `id`.

```js
const
    one = [{ id: 1, field1: "a" }, { id: 2, field1: "b" }, { id: 3, field1: "c" }, { id: 4, field1: "d" }],
    two = [{ id: 4, field2: "4" }, { id: 1, field2: "1" }],
    fromOne = Object.fromEntries(one.map((object, index) => [object.id, { object, index }])),
    result = two
        .map(o => ({ ...fromOne[o.field2].object, ...o }))
        .sort((a, b) => fromOne[a.field2].index - fromOne[b.field2].index);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it looks like you are sorting by ID. Like I said, this is only coincidentally the order that i want. I want the order of the first array