# Join mysql user and post angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to combine posts and users in AngularJS, for example in a database like this. There are 2 data that are the same, namely user_id, then I want to display the username data?

```
[post: {post_id: 1, user_id: 2,  date: 18-05-1997}];
```

```
[user: {user_id: 2, fullname: herman, username: herman_man}];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the data should be joined and returned from the database/api layer to the front-end.
However, if that is not possible, there are many ways to do this. One simple way is to do a `map` and return a new ViewModel. Something like this:

```
export class PostViewModel {
   post_id: number;
   user_name?: string;
   date: Date;
   user_id: number;
}
//then in the method where you retrieve the data, after retrieving it:
// let's say you have the collections named: users and posts
let postsVm = posts.map(x=> <PostViewModel>{
              post_id: x.post_id,
              user_name: users.find(y=>y.user_id === x.user_id)?.username,
              date: x.date,
              user_id: x.user_id
              });
// this should return an array of PostViewModels you can then use in the UI to display.
```

I haven't executed the code above, it's meant to be a guide on how to do this. I've done something similar in my code.

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394741/javascript-sql-like-join-of-two-arrays) is another SO article with other advanced options to try.