# How to ensure typing of one key belongs to other type key

Tags: typescript

This is somewhat similar to database foreign key relationship.

Let's say have user table and there is address table and user.address belongs to address table key so how do we ensure that only those id which are in address table will be allowed?

```
type Address = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  state: string;
  country: string; 
}

type User = {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  location: Address['id'] // it shoud be Address.id
}

const address: Address[] = [{
    id: 'in',
    name: 'BLR',
    state: 'KA',
    country: 'India'
},
{
    id: 'us',
    name: 'NY',
    state: 'NY',
    country: 'USA'
}
];

const user: User [] = [
    {
        name: 'admin',
        gender: 'male',
        location: 'in'
    },
    {
        name: 'user',
        gender: 'female',
        location: 'uk' << this should give error
    }
];
```

Comment: [playground-link](https://tsplay.dev/NDa01m)

Comment: and how can you sure that it does not show any research effort?  dont be arrogant be kind. what else could be the reason to ask the question? if you know the answer then please provide amd dont show un necessary assumptions

Comment: @Luuk and if it is unclear then what exactly is unclear? I see your profile and there is not a single answer regarding *typescript* so it imply that are not aware about typescript then how can you say its unclear. what a pity.

Comment: For example the text "// it shoud be Address.id" is confusing? Why is it in the question, What purpose does this comment have ??  Second example: "will be allowed" It is unclear what the nature of this statement is. What is the expected output ?

Comment: You have to understand what OP wants and there is playground link also.

Comment: From: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): 1) "Search, and research": It is not clear what you did do with that  2) "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem": The description is vague, and not specific. 3) "Introduce the problem before you post any code"  code? did you post any (related to the question you have)??

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the information , I am on SO since last 14 years so I know very well how abd what to ask.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I am NEW to typescript, but ....:

```
const innerJoin = (xs: any[], ys: any[], sel: { ({ id: id,name,state,country }: { id: any; name: any; state: any; country: any; },{ location: lname,gender,location }: { location: any; gender: any; }): false|{ aid: any; name: any; state: any; country: any; }; (arg0: any,arg1: any): any; }) =>
    xs.reduce((zs, x) =>
    ys.reduce((zs, y) =>        // cartesian product - all combinations
    zs.concat(sel(x, y) || []), // filter out the rows and columns you want
    zs), []);

const result = innerJoin(address, user, 
    ({ id: aid, name, state, country }, { location: lname, gender, location }) =>
        location === aid && { aid,name,state,country});

console.log(result);
```

result:

```
[LOG]: [{
  "aid": "in",
  "name": "BLR",
  "state": "KA",
  "country": "India"
}]
```

The result only contains the inner join between the `address` and `user`.

Use this answer to put this together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17500836/724039

see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAThAziqBeKBvAUFKASzgC4oVhFCA7AcwG58pqBDAWwjIqrsYIpbBO5SjQZMAxgHsArtUoguo3lFwBfXLlCQoAVRQREmHE1YclPcQVoRqcQxbF8oAGykTBhKdTLwkqFABtAHJiYIBdKAB6KKJgcgALWRc4KAAjaD9kNAA6YnVNaWoKKBYEbJRfcoDAyKxAvAICYjJQ6mCAGiYCM2FggCEAGQAlTu6RQT6AaRgxpqhpOQVWgEk7QhZg9S7GppaoYJkUOabe1oA5AE0T-mBJi+uu+cX5REUD3QBlWYLwxlwiiUjg49AYjLVjIFxrt5j12H0ymwaDdYTY7CDgmwWC4ICj5m4PMAvD4Dsjxmonk0YbCzgdgYg8U00fZEK0AGYQLE4xkEAmebytGQAa2CqnmGj+AO8KCkOJyEhxLEQAAoAJSMQGyiA5Ny0ZUAIgAKgBRT6G-XqqXFLU6qR6sr+NCWzVy3XK+nO6U2t36jB+jAW-6A+I0aiGABSUhoxmVAA9KqVqCBah0oCAEywkynyBAXGRsFBlQX9sQOr0OgIhB0XgooGp80RSImQPRmPCyJmWxMhB2k62a29e12KQW+USBa5y8zDB0x8S6w25xPO63p6zm621KqyGzsQYAD4Flj7Fdt8wb7vCU8D96ntSt5VK2gABiHHSfAEYh9uL1vMAA+cZ4xyZA4BkCQIGVZUAC8UFTWNVQA8Z0xAiAwIgqDYNTEBEIwf9YSaGIFiVIQUA2agoDARApHQ+IAFpShcFwFikNg0hoflinGWD5W8QllQMFw42wxD933KBalVVMiLZQgXCEIxZHiYAEmgaiAHd0EzVJpBcGQ2GKNNZCgdTM2AbiUCkiTwktK0SmyGR5OMUMIyjahH2qNBU3pVNxiLRsO1LM8IFTSsQpYpY3jrVNR3cTiyBccsoDXVMlwov88PGfE4vHCj-VKYgoAAMiKnACrgMt4QrO4qxvLcgy9V07WVBz5MtIA

Comment: P.S. Yes, I do see 2 errors when using this link to that playground, but I am NEW to Typescript, and do not want/need to put effort in solving these two errors.

Comment: As long as I do not get informative feedback on what is wrong, I cannot help you. So I can repeat the OP, and say: "Please show some decency to give some description while downvoting. No answer given but just downvoted." ....  

Comment: O, BTW, I do **not** post stuff like "in top *** SO users in *** since years." on my profile, because I do not care which position I have there.... 